# I want to provide face id authentication for login to user so that user does not have to type id and password each time

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Is there a way to perform Face ID Authentication for Log In in Xamarin.Android Application. A same feature like iPhoneX face id authentication?

For that I want to check that if device supports face id or not? If its supported than is it turned on from settings or not? This is the flow I'm looking to achieve in Xamarin.Android!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Biometrics with iris and face recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51146127/biometrics-with-iris-and-face-recognition)

Comment: no,it's not duplicate question.

Comment: The biggest disadvantage at the moment is that the BiometricPrompt can be used only on Android P and above. I

Comment: Have a try with Firebase ML Kit.https://medium.com/devnibbles/facial-recognition-with-android-1-4-5e043c264edc

Comment: but how I compare from device if set already face Id.